# I am trying to sort the map in decreasing order but i am not getting the desired result?

Tags: c++, ordered-map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;

    map<char, int,greater <int>> m;
    m['A'] = 1;
    m['C'] = 1;
    m['G'] = 1;
    m['T'] = 1;
    for(ll i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == s[i+1])  //ATTCGGGA
            m[s[i]]++;
    
    }

    for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
    {
        cout <<it->first <<" " <<it->second<<endl;
    }
    //cout <<it->second<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

my desired output should be
G 3
T 2
A 1
C 1
but its showing
T 2
G 3
C 1
A 1
I dont know why this is happening as i have already mentioned it to be greater in the orderedmap.
Please kindly solve the issue?

Comment: `map`s are sorted according to the `key`s, not the `value`s. i.e. `TCGA` since you've specified `greater`.

Comment: but we can sort it by values using greater<int> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/descending-order-in-map-and-multimap-of-cplusplus-stl

Comment: No, you can't. the 3rd parameter specifies ordering of keys only. (So it should be `greater<char>` actually.) Which gives `TGCA`

Comment: @TheAnonymous -- The `map` does not use the value to sort.  It uses the key, so your `greater<int>` did exactly what you told it to do -- it sorted the keys in descending order.

Comment: @TheAnonymous -- Basically you accomplished the first part of the assignment, which is to get a count of each of the characters.  The second part of the assignment, where you have to take the counts and sort them in descending order, is the part of the assignment you have not completed.

Answer (score 0):

you could just simply use a queue.
If you want to do it with a map use a multi_map(); and use the int as the key and the char as the value that way u will sort them according to the int value